# Creating a skewed triangle shape

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

Is it possible to create the shape produced by this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neu3kqb8/). But then with no JavaScript but CSS3 (with `<div>`) ?

Basically this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i += 1) {
    if(coords[(i + 1)] != undefined) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(coords[i].x, coords[i].y);
        ctx.lineTo(coords[(i + 1)].x, coords[(i + 1)].y);
        ctx.stroke();
    } else {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(coords[i].x, coords[i].y);
        ctx.lineTo(coords[0].x, coords[0].y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

So you have points that needs to connect to each other?

Comment: This isn't really clear. What DOM elements should the connections be made of ? divs ? SVG elements ? And how would you define the points if not in JS ? In the CSS ?

Comment: of-course.. create an image  in photoshop. use as a background of element

Comment: @NaeemShaikh no, thats not what I want!

Comment: @DazDylz please add more context to your question. Right now it seems unclear what you are trying to do. make the shape ? connect points? witch points and how do you define them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `svg`, if you don't want to use `canvas`.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <path d="M0 0 l100 10 l-40 90z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

---

Path command for `8,8,10,10,30,30,49,10` would be `M8 8 L10 10 L30 40 L49 10z`.

```html
<svg width="49" height="40" viewBox="0 0 50 41">
  <path d="M8 8 L10 10 L30 40 L49 10z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

---

To apply a click event to the shape, you could use `pointer-events: all` on `#test`.

```css
#test {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<svg width="49" height="40" viewBox="0 0 50 41">
  <path id="test" d="M8 8 L10 10 L30 40 L49 10z" fill="none" onclick="alert('Works')" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Well, how do I convert this: `8,8,10,10,30,30,49,10` to `M0 0 l100 10 l-40,90z`? with javascript

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer: *"with no javascript but CSS3 (with <div>"*

Comment: Thanks, but is it also possible when you click IN the shape that you get a alert? http://jsfiddle.net/fag24asL/

Comment: @DazDylz - Ofcourse it is. Since the `fill` of the shape is `none` you will have to give the id `#test` to the `svg` tag or use a group(`g` tag) if you want to add more shapes and have different alerts for each. ---> [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fag24asL/1/)

Comment: @DazDylz - Or you apply `pointer-events: all` to `#test` ----> http://jsfiddle.net/fag24asL/4/

Comment: To all who are reading this thread (just re-iterating my point), this answer is the best for this question and such shapes.

Answer (score 3):

> **Note:** Posting this answer just because you asked with CSS3, but the complexity and possible calculation overhead involved in this approach is proof enough why CSS shouldn't be used for this. Please do not use this approach.

A bit of explanation on how this was achieved:

1. A `div` is created with top and right border (1px black) and the other two borders are set to none.
2. This `div` is then skewed a bit to make it appear as though the edge on the right side is a bit slanted.
3. Inside the shape, a pseudo-element with only a right border is created and it is also skewed to produce the diagonal line from the right-bottom to the left-top. Transform origin is set as right-bottom to avoid positioning overhead.
4. An anchor tag is added within the parent `div` and the overflow is set to hidden so that only the portion within the shape is clickable.
5. The user select on the anchor tag are disabled to prevent a double click from selecting a blank space within the `div`.
6. Finally the whole container `div` is rotated a bit to make it look as though the triangle is not parallel to x-axis.

```js
document.getElementById("clickme").onclick = function() {
  alert('Hi! I work alright.');
}
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 45px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(5deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(5deg);
  transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(5deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
a {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  margin-left: 0px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  content: '';
  height: 50px;
  width: 45px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(42deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
  -moz-transform: skew(42deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: skew(42deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#" id="clickme"></a>
</div>
```

---

Another option to create a skewed triangle shape would be to use `clip-path` like in below snippet. The shape is created by applying the same `clip-path` on the main container element and a pseudo-element which is smaller than the container.

```js
document.getElementById("clickme").onclick = function() {
  alert('Hi! I work alright.');
}
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: black;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 20%, 70% 100%);
}
div:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 5px);
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  top: 2px;
  left: 3px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 20%, 70% 100%);
}

/* Just for demo */

div{
  transition: all 1s;
}
div:hover{
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clickme"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by embeding SVG as CSS. Quote from: 
http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

"Another way to use SVG's is to convert them into Data URI's. Data URI's might not save you actual file size, but can be more efficient because the data is right there. It doesn't require an additional HTTPRequest.

Mobilefish.com has an online conversion tool for that (http://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php). Simply paste in the contents of your SVG file and fill out the form and it will display the results in a textarea for you to copy. Remember to remove line breaks in the data it gives you back. 
...
You can use that anywhere we've talked about so far (except inline  because that just doesn't make sense) Just put the gibberish where it says [data] in these examples.

As CSS

.logo {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,[data]);
}
"